# Need Help - Complex SQL Querying

Tags: sql

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQFfr.jpg)

Consider the Table above.

**NOTE:** Expected Rows are highlighted in Yellow color
1. If the user provide Make = 'Make1', Model='Model1', EffectiveDate = ''.

[Expected Result-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lnN1.jpg) - Should Return all Vin with respective latest effective date

2. If the user provide Make = 'Make1', Model='Model1', EffectiveDate = '01/01/2014'.

   [Expected Result - 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2cz7.jpg) Should return all Vin with nearest or equal effective date.
3. If the user provide Make = 'Make1', Model='Model1', EffectiveDate = '05/01/2013'.

   [Expected Result - 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PM7d.jpg) Should return all Vin with nearest or equal effective date. (which is 01/2013 in this case)

Comment: Tag your question with the DBMS you are using

Comment: Also post the query you're currently using. You need to put in some effort here. It does you no good if we do your homework for you.